# Can I install an IDE (PATA) optical drive in a 2009 Mac Pro?

Tags: upgrade, mac-pro, optical-drive, sata

The 2009 Mac Pro uses SATA for its optical drive bays.  I have an older IDE (PATA) DVD burner I'd like to use with it.

I know there are IDE-SATA adapters, but they take up some space, and the fit with many internal components is pretty tight.  Is there room in a Mac Pro for an IDE optical drive, plus an IDE-SATA adapter so it can be plugged in?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

As long as you have only one optical drive installed in your MacPro, you have a full 5.25" bay either under or above it available to stuff something into. I have a pair of SSDs installed in my lower optical bay.

Shorter answer:

If the IDE-SATA adapter is smaller than the optical drive, I'd pull the chassis and see if it fits.